# how to substitute duplicated rows in a dataset with a row with the mean values but keeping the index of the first row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset with some duplicated rows. until now i usually dropped the duplicated columns with

```
df = df.reset_index()
df.drop_duplicates(subset="CID",keep="first")   





missing_rows = ~df.isin(df2).all(axis=1)
missing_index = df.loc[missing_rows].index
```

but i would really like to substitute the first row with a row with the mean values while keeping the index of the first row. i need to preserve the right index because after that i need to remove the corresponding columns and rows from the covariance matrix.

i tried with

```
# create a new column with the index of the first occurrence of each row
df['first_index'] = df.groupby(['CID' ]).transform('first').index

# group the rows by their values and compute the mean of each group
df2 = df.groupby(['CID' ]).mean() 
 
uff= df.drop_duplicates(subset="CID",keep="first")
# set the index of the mean rows to the index of the first occurrence of each row
df2.index = uff["first_index"]
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here in df.assign a column with averages is created. In `'ind'` , the indexes of the `'first'` rows by group are collected in a list. And  through `'loc'` the necessary lines are selected.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'CID': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'C'],
                   'val': [1, 2, 0.5, 3, 1, 2, 0.6]})



df = df.assign(avg = df.groupby('CID').transform('mean'))
ind = df.groupby('CID').apply(lambda x: x.index[0])

df1 = df.loc[ind].copy()
```

df

```
  CID  val       avg
0   A  1.0  0.833333
1   B  2.0  2.000000
2   A  0.5  0.833333
3   C  3.0  1.866667
4   A  1.0  0.833333
5   C  2.0  1.866667
6   C  0.6  1.866667
```

df1

```
  CID  val       avg
0   A  1.0  0.833333
1   B  2.0  2.000000
3   C  3.0  1.866667
```